# Use proc in Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In ruby on rails guide, there is a section [5.3 Using a Proc with :if and :unless](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless) discussed about **Using a Proc with :if and :unless** in validation helper. It gives the following example:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_confirmation_of :password,
    :unless => Proc.new { |a| a.password.blank? }
end
```

Does this '**a**' in Proc refers to the current Account instance? Can I understand it(the 'a') as the reference of the current Account instance?

is the `:password` and `a.password` point at the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is precisely what it is. `a` refers to the object being validated.